# CSS: responsive design, position card to fit in the middle any size of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have this piece of code that has the profile card in the middle of screen regardless what the screen size is. It often appears too small for any type of screen. How can I position the profile card to almost fill the screen?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: #303633;
  background-color: #C8D9E7;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 35px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  background-color: #e1306c;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 30px rgba(225, 48, 108, 0.4);
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #e75d8c;
}

.content-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 530px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fbfcee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-wrapper .img {
  width: 302px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-wrapper img {
  /*
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}




.profile--info {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.profile--info span {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Adobe Blank";
  z-index: 1;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 0.575em;
  color: rgba(84, 95, 89, 0.75);
  display: block;
}
.profile--info span.username {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
}
.profile--info span.userquote {
  margin-top: -15px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: rgba(84, 95, 89, 0.75);
}

.user {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  max-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.user-social-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.user-social-wrapper .user-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: 200;
  flex: 1 1;
}
.user-social-wrapper .user-info span:first-child {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.user-social-wrapper .user-info span:last-child {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: rgba(84, 95, 89, 0.75);
}

.shots {
  width: calc(100% + 60px);
  margin-left: -30px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.shots .shot {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.shots .shot img {
  transition: all 0.255s;
  width: 102px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="user">
        <div class="shots">
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fcc951ea7fb4756657e6a7d042bf28f3/5CB41E95/t51.2885-15/e35/44305549_353634695394272_4379074065337998962_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTkxMjA0MDQ0OTAyMTY1Njc4Mg%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/cc7f49ae37334eff4a2e844ffbebaa21/5CB841C6/t51.2885-15/e35/41336764_2309590515939856_3014107714986624367_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTg3Nzg1Mjk1Njk0NDkwNTAwMg%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d8b9d0e098128aad6eac6c39c19439cb/5CD059B2/t51.2885-15/e35/46699770_789255231412285_7247415646102729111_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTkyMjcyMTIwOTQyODk0Mjc5NQ%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a0efc75790b1d1a20306b4b9ee8c0d31/5C9D1D98/t51.2885-15/e35/42593422_668756993510074_548785136612309253_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTg4MjI5MDk5MzYyODEwOTk0Mw%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/fa49d4e551525ac7a288784e0866f7cf/5CD53EA6/t51.2885-15/e35/44442144_2039456152959656_8454847146314760657_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTkxMTEwMTUwMTEzOTEzMzk4MA%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/845ad7174d012da1d1b62ac375d2b466/5CD46203/t51.2885-15/e35/43816352_986229031581012_2433270463824730761_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTg5NTQwODg2MDE5NjA5OTA1NQ%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7d4877bc850a66d5aeb539c5510add7e/5C9BD445/t51.2885-15/e35/43621864_2280294755587222_1177965970195440793_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTg4NjY0MTkwODQ0MTE4MDcyOQ%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/5252d016bae25d4ef4bca9e0c0a0306b/5CCFD742/t51.2885-15/e35/42927631_265838184102659_8658034749053379565_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTkxNjkzMDk2MDM3NTMwNTUzOA%3D%3D.2"></div>
                        <div class="shot"><img src="https://scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/880acf9db110584cb44b3b69ad0a366f/5CB3E901/t51.2885-15/e35/41866047_1814622118587789_2219135764187038727_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-icn1-1.cdninstagram.com&se=7&ig_cache_key=MTg4NDI5OTEwNzU1ODU4OTEzMg%3D%3D.2"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="profile--info"><span class="username">ʏɪɴʀᴜɪ ᴅᴇɴɢ</span><span>☺@bobby_dyr</span><br/><span class="userquote">In 2018, ʏɪɴʀᴜɪ ᴅᴇɴɢ received 164❤️, 7✉️ per post by average, and a total of</span></div>
        <div class="user-social-wrapper">
          <div class="user-info user-posts"><span>104</span><span>Shots</span></div>
          <div class="user-info user-followers"><span>16,964</span><span>Likes</span></div>
          <div class="user-info user-following"><span>643</span><span>Comments</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have this piece of code that has the profile card in the middle of screen regardless what the screen size is. It often appears too small for any type of screen. How can I position the profile card to almost fill the screen?

Basically what should I do to adjust it from [(too small)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObsJR.png)to this [(ideal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZhvi.png)

Comment: `.content-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 530px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #fbfcee;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}` use this code

Comment: does not work @ShahjehanAliChughtai

Comment: you need something like this http://prntscr.com/lzptti ?

Answer (score 1):

Just change it:

```
 .shots .shot {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 33%; // <-- change it
        height: 100px;
        flex-grow: 1; // <-- add
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use media queries and target the classes you want to amend on the different screen sizes to make it fit as you need. Some useful links:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

In your case, you would need to amend the width of the card to 100% on mobile to achieve the design on your screenshot. Hope that makes sense! :)